# jQuery - Highest value from array - but lower than x

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

My problem is that I have an array with numbers and I want to get the highest number that is lower than e.g. 6.

So if I have an array like this:

> 10, 5, 19, 2, 1, 32, 3

I only want to get the number 5.

I tried to sort the array from highest to lowest like this:

```
str = "<?php echo $timings;?>"
res = str.split(",");
res.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
alert(res);
```

But I never figured out a way to get the first value lower than x.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be duplicate numbers?

Comment: You don't really need jQuery for this. Plain JS is fine.

Comment: Do you *need* to sort, or was that just your approach to finding the number?

Comment: You can not do `.sort` on a PHP array. You need to either use AJAX or sort it on PHP side and get max value and just return max value. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert string like looking array to real array using `.split(/[,\s]+/)`.

Then you can just use `Math.max` along with `Array.prototype.filter`.

Like this:

```
var res = "<?php echo $timings;?>".split(/[,\s]+/);
var num = Math.max.apply(null,res.filter(function(x){
   return  x < 6
}));
```

Basically what the above does is find all numbers less than 6 using `.filter()` and then taking the largest number from the returned array using `Math.max`

Comment: This wont work with the current scenario. This works on JS arrays but the returned data in question is array from PHP.

Comment: You never use `g` with `split`.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown:

```
res = "<?php echo $timings;?>"
res.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

That would be a string by the time it gets to JavaScript. If what the browser sees is:

```
res = "10, 5, 19, 2, 1, 32, 3"
res.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

...then the first step is to turn that string into an array, which you can do like this:

```
var a = res.split(/[,\s]+/);
```

Then, just loop through the array and look:

```
var lowest;
a.forEach(function(num) {
    if (num < 6 && (lowest === undefined || lowest > num)) {
        lowest = num;
    }
});
```

That's using ES5's `forEach`, which *nearly* all environments now have (but IE8 doesn't). Details on how to loop through arrays can be found in [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446/157247) and its answers.

Or if you need to know the *index* of the lowest number:

```
var a = [10, 5, 19, 2, 1, 32, 3];
var lowest, lowestIndex = -1;
a.forEach(function(num, index) {
    if (num < 6 && (lowest === undefined || lowest > num)) {
        lowest = num;
        lowestIndex = index;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will work on JS arrays, if you look at question the array is returned from PHP on which this would not work.

Comment: The question's really unclear. I've updated a bit to try to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from PHP anyways why not return the value instead of array?

You could first remove the array elements that are greater than X:

`$filtered = array_filter($timings, function ($x) { return $x < $y; });`

Now you are left with an array that contains elements that are **less than or equal to x**

Now just get the max value:

`$max = max($filtered);`

Comment: why did I get vote down? OP clearly is getting an array from PHP, you can not just apply JS functions to a variable that holds a PHP array ?